# How to sum on specified column in a RDD

Tags: rdd

Here are two data files:

```
spark16/file1.txt
1,9,5
2,7,4
3,8,3

spark16/file2.txt
1,g,h
2,i,j
3,k,l
```

After joined, I have:

```
(1, ((9,5),(g,h)) )
(2, ((7,4),(i,j)) )
(3, ((8,3),(k,l)) )
```

I need to get the

> sum of (5,4,3) = 12

I stuck here:

```
val file1 = sc.textFile(“data96/file1.txt”).map(x=>(x.split(",")(0).toInt, (x.split(",")(1), x.split(",")(2).toInt)))
val file2 = sc.textFile(“data96/file2.txt”).map(x=>(x.split(",")(0).toInt, (x.split(",")(1), x.split(",")(2))))

val joined = file1.join(file2)
val sorted = joined.sortByKey()

val first = sorted.first
res4: (Int, ((String, Int), (String, String))) = (1,((9,5),(g,h)))

scala> joined.reduce(_._2._1._2 + _._2._1.2)
:34: error: type mismatch;
found : Int
required: (Int, ((String, Int), (String, String)))
joined.reduce(._2._1._2 + _._2._1._2)
```

How can I get the sum on the **_._2._1._2**?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you got this after `join` 
then

```
(1, ((9,5),(g,h)) )
(2, ((7,4),(i,j)) )
(3, ((8,3),(k,l)) )
```

Then select the column only you require as and perform the reduce

```
joined.map(_._2._1._2).reduce(_ + _)
```

This should give you the sum of `5, 4, 3` as `12`

`Reduce` must return as same as the `dataType` you `passed`

Hope this helps!

Comment: intersting finding: joined.map(_._2._1._2)reduce(_+_) 
is also accepted (note there is no 'dot' after the map

Comment: and why my above comment is missing a _ in the reduce?